# How to set search interface in a Custom Spinner in Android

Tags: android, search, autocomplete, dialog, spinner

I am new to android trying to create a custom spinner which hold so many of data in list so i made the spinnermode as dialog and now i want to make the searchable interface or autocomplete text on the dialog of the spinner as shown in below image and sorry i am unable to post the image with this post so i made it visible by clicking the below link.
Help Me to get the result.
Advance thanx
![enter image description here][1]

http://s28.postimg.org/w0h6qq959/dialogwithsearch.png

Comment: Hey @Suresh How to solve this query? Can you suggest me. I have the same query. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Using an autocomplete textview will make it so much easier.

You can take a look at this tutorial for that:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_auto_complete.htm

Comment: how to bring the autocomplete text view inside the dialog?

Comment: @SureshKumarSelvaraj you can create a Dialog Fragment with a custom layout. https://github.com/thecodepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-DialogFragment

Comment: have u seen the image?